# Creating variables which can be passed across multiple ViewControllers. Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 VC's that work perfectly when run. However, the array's are located in the Global area. This seems risky. If I move them down to the FirstViewController class they will not be passed to the SecondViewController.

Is there a way they can be rewritten or declared to make it safer? I have tried a multitude of solutions but can't seem to find the correct code syntax.

FirstViewController

```
import UIKit

var siteName = ["Google", "Yahoo", "YouTube"]
var siteAddress = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.youtube.com"]
var row = 0

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return siteName.count
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = siteName[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        row = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,  WKUIDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var navBarTitle: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewConnect: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navBarTitle.title = siteName[row]

        let myURL = URL(string: siteAddress[row])
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webViewConnect.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

*** Revised Working Code ***

MasterViewController

```
import UIKit

class siteVars {
    var siteName = ["Google", "Yahoo", "YouTube"]
    var siteAddress = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.youtube.com"]
    var siteRow = 0
}
```

FirstViewController

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var siteData = siteVars()

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return siteData.siteName.count
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = siteData.siteName[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        siteData.siteRow = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.siteData.siteRow = siteData.siteRow
        }
    }
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,  WKUIDelegate {

    var siteData = siteVars()

    @IBOutlet weak var navBarTitle: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewConnect: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navBarTitle.title = siteData.siteName[siteData.siteRow]

        let myURL = URL(string: siteData.siteAddress[siteData.siteRow])
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webViewConnect.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use MVC (Model View Controller) Architecture. Create Model class that would store the data. This model could be created in the AppDelegate and passed to every view controller during the creating of a new view controller or while doing a segue. That way all view controllers have access to the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, got me going in the right direction. Did my research and created a MasterViewController swift file to reference data from. Didn't use the AppDelegate as this is not recommended as best practice. See above for the new code structure.